# “Indicator Applet Complete" has quit unexpectedly

Tags: 18.04, panel, mate, ubuntu-mate, applet

I have been repeatedly getting an error upon logging into Ubuntu MATE saying that my "indicator applet complete" has quit unexpectedly. I can choose to reload it which fixes it, but when I reboot the computer or log out and log back in, the error comes back. I have found that running `killall mate-panel` once the error comes up will work to fix it. I tried making the computer run `killall mate-panel` every time I log in, but it doesn't always work correctly and when it does work, the error will show up for a second or two before the command runs and resets the panel, getting rid of the error. By the way, I am running Ubuntu MATE 18.04.
If anybody knows a solution, please share.

UPDATE:
my MATE Tweak window has these options available to me:
[image: MATE Tweak panel settings]

Comment: If anybody has any ideas whatsoever, please share. I really need to find a solution to this problem

Comment: Try to run MATE Tweak with `mate-tweak`, then toggle all indicators from *Panel (Interface)* -> *Enable indicators*.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm in MATE tweak, but what do you mean by toggling all indicators?

Comment: I mean [this checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRXmA.png) (ran on 16.04 LTS, but 18.04 should have similar). Try to uncheck it and then check again.

Comment: I don't have anything like that. I will post a picture of the mate-tweak menu in my original question above.

Comment: Just started 18.04 LTS VM, do not see this option too. You may consider to ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: I tried re-installing the "indicator applet complete" package, which did not fix anything. I might try re-installing the whole mate panel? I don't know if that would be very effective, and I'm concerned it might mess up some other stuff. Anyway, I'll ask around on the ubuntu-mate community and see if I can get any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking at a file called .x11errors in my home directory and found that indicator-applications couldn't load.
This is because

.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home

was set to root privilege and should be user privilege.
After that, my indicator-applet-complete errors no longer showed.

Comment: Thank you. I assume this would work, so I marked it as correct, but I have since re-installed Ubuntu MATE and the problem no longer persists. Thank you very much!

Comment: doesn't work for me. I tried even: chwon nobody:nogroup with 0666.

Comment: This worked for me after installing Mate over Ubuntu 18.04. I suggest changing permissions for all files in your user folder: `cd ~ ; sudo chown --recursive user:user ./`

Answer (score 0):

This workaround works. Put the script in your Startup Programs.
@dawciobiel

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Simulate Return key
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sleep 5

xte 'key Return'
```